# Download file in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and I trying to capture the filename stored on the database table called "Infrastructure" so that I can create a link for users to downloading that file. The download works but I always get the wrong file stored in the directory.

So in my controller called infrastructureController.php I have these codes.

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $infrastructure = $this->infrastructureRepository->find($id);
        $Attachment = $infrastructure->inf_file; // captured filename in the database

        if (empty($infrastructure)) {
            Flash::error('Infrastructure not found');

            return redirect(route('infrastructures.index'));
        }

        return view('infrastructures.show')->with('infrastructure', $infrastructure);
    }
```

In my route or web.php

I have these codes...

```
Route::get('/download', function(){
    $name = $Attachment;

    $file = storage_path()."/app/public/infrastructure/".$Attachment;

    $headers  = array(
        'Content-Type: application/pdf',
    );

    return Response::download($file, $name, $headers);
});
```

and finally, in my view file, I have this

```
<!-- Inf File Field   -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('inf_file', 'Attachements:') !!}
    <a href="/download">Download Now</a>
</div>
```

Can someone point out I did wrong here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you are not passing the name of the attachment from your View back to your controller so change your view to:

```php
<!-- Inf File Field   -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('inf_file', 'Attachements:') !!}
    <a href="/download/{{ $infrastructure->inf_file }}">Download Now</a>
</div>
```

Then in your route you need to access the name of the file like so:

```php
Route::get('/download/{Attachment}', function($Attachment){
    $name = $Attachment;

    $file = Storage::disk('public')->get("infrastructure/".$Attachment);

    $headers  = array(
        'Content-Type: application/pdf',
    );

    return Response::download($file, $name, $headers);
});
```

Comment: so the variable that I used to store the filename in my controller ($Attachment) did not pass the file name to the route.

Comment: I fixed the view so that it uses your filename since you weren't passing $Attachment to your view.

Comment: Adding that filename allows me to download the file but it's always Failed - No File. I am starting to believe that the files I am trying to download are not public, Could you please confirm that this permission will allow me to download the files.

-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 446656 Apr  5 21:44 Infras-1586079862.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 140555 Apr  5 21:57 Infras-1586080678.pdf

Comment: I rarely use `Response::downlooad()` it appears we need to pass the actual file and not just the file path. I updated my edit to pass the actual file with this  `$file = Storage::disk('public')->get("infrastructure/".$Attachment);`

Comment: Finally, it worked, I made changes based on what you suggested but I have to change it to the right directory which is `$file = storage_path()."/app/public/infrastructure/".$Attachement;`